# How do I add a simple namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, linq-to-xml

How do I make this line in my xml? (the problem is the namespace)

The closes I came was this:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
XElement root = new XElement("root", 
    new XAttribute("name", Name),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns, Namespace)//<-- XNamespace.Xmlns is not good
);
```

I have tryed with new XAttribute("xmlns", Namespace) also, but I just don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this. It works great.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
XElement root = new XElement("root", 
    new XAttribute("name", Name)
    );
doc.Add(root);
XNamespace xmlns = Namespace;
doc.Root.Name = xmlns + root.Name.LocalName;
```